# what is diffrent between RSA and rsa -des3?

Tags: cryptography, rsa

what is different between 2 command in open ssl tools?
**openssl genrsa -des3 -out privkey.pem 2048** and **openssl genrsa -out privkey.pem 2048**?

thanks

Comment: This question should be asked on a different site about cryptography. SO is more about coding. There is the Sysadmin site which could help on StackExchange. StackOverflow would be a place to help you if you had problem implementing those algorithms.

Answer (score 18):

The `-des3` option [specifies how the private key is encrypted](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/genrsa.html) with a password. Without a cipher option, the private key is not encrypted, and no password is required.

Password encryption can protect the private key even when file-system–based access control is circumvented.

Answer (score 12):

According to the [docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/genrsa.html#):

> **-aes128|-aes192|-aes256|-camellia128|-camellia192|-camellia256|-des|-des3|-idea**
> These options encrypt the private key with specified cipher before
> outputting it. If none of these options is specified no encryption is
> used. If encryption is used a pass phrase is prompted for if it is not
> supplied via the -passout argument.

DES is an encryption method and DES3 (also called triple DES) is the same method only that it runs 3 times in a row to make the encryption stronger.

DES3 is a standard that is being heavily used (`-des3`), for example, when your browser is being redirected to port 443 (SSL), after the RSA key exchange, DES3 is being used (with the RSA key) for the rest of the session.